# CPU super load with 'filter: blur()' effect on animated gif

Tags: css, cpu-usage, animated-gif, css-filters

I am geeking some visuals rendering in browser and I have a background animated gif that takes full size of the view port:

```
.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150%;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    background-image: url('blabla.gif')
}
```

Problem: my CPU shoots to the stars with the gaussian blur to be applied on an animated gif.

Can you think of a way to have this blur effect without so much CPU cost? I looked around and all examples uses filter: blur() but most are on normal images so the problem is not there in those cases.

Cheers!

Comment: Probably your only relatively better bet is webgl and canvas and doing it with a GLSL shader.

Comment: _“Can you think of a way to have this blur effect without so much CPU cost?”_ – don’t apply a filter later on, but blur the GIF’s content directly inside the image already …?

Comment: Do we still use GIFs?

Comment: @Cbroe well I wanted to avoid that =D

Comment: @SalmanA yes... at least in this little experiments yes